# Show box-shadow through transparent object (div)

Tags: html, background, show, transparent, css

I'm working on a css3 3D page and i want to show the shadow through a transparent div but i can't get this to work...
I can't use a span or anything because it needs to be the same object because of jquery animation.
**The basic div styling:**

```
#Div3{
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid white;
        border-radius:10px;        
        transition: all 1s;
        background:transparent;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

**Adittional class for position + shadow + transform:**

```
.P3{
        top:22.5%;
        bottom:25%;
        right:25%;
        height:55%;
        width:20%;
        margin-right:-10%;
        box-shadow:10px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
        transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateY( 330deg );
        -webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateY( 330deg );
    }
```

**Result:**

The background is set to transparent but it won't show the box-shadow behind it,

- Does box-shadow only generates a shadow for the outline of the
  object?
- Is there a way to make it visible using css?

Answer (score 2):

He wants the shadow (the dark part) to also show on the inside of the outline. That is, having shadow on both sides of the outline.

Maybe this will help:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,1));
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly know why doesn't work for you. Box shadow does show on transparent background, as you can see on the example.

Maybe you should try placing the shadow on the firs class definition for your element, #Div3.

```
.cartContainer{
width:150px;
height:60px;
border-radius:10px;
background:transparent;
float:left;
margin:-10px 0 0 15px;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px  #FFFF99, #333 0 0 5px;
```

}

Example: [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5pc6/)